# How to decorate child method with parent method

Tags: python, python-decorators

Can i decorate child methods with parent method where i extract some common code? The Design and structure of classes must be preserved.
I have:

```
class Parent:

    def general_create(self, create_child_func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print("Some general actions before")
            result = create_child_func(*args, **kwargs)
            print("Some general actions after")
            return result
        return wrapper


class A(Parent):
    def create(self):
        print("Сreate actions for class A")
        return "Result A"


class B(Parent):
    def create(self):
        print("Сreate actions for class B")
        return "Result B"
```

I thought it should be like this (but of course it doesn't work):

```
class Child(Parent):

@Parent.general_create # or @super().general_create
def create(self):
    print("Сreate actions for class Child")
    return "Result Child"
```

Comment: This design is quite weird and it's not really clear how you want to use it.

Comment: Nothing about the decorator is specific to `Parent`; it should probably be defined as a regular function.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how you want to use this code...
Nonetheless if you want to call `general_create` from the `Parent` class and not an instance of it (e.g. calling `@Parent.general_create`) then it needs to be a static method (class method would work but you are not using the class):

```py
class Parent:
    @staticmethod
    def general_create(create_child_func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print("Some general actions before")
            result = create_child_func(*args, **kwargs)
            print("Some general actions after")
            return result

        return wrapper


class Child(Parent):
    @Parent.general_create
    def create(self):
        print("Сreate actions for class Child")
        return "Result Child"


Child().create()
```

Whith this usage though there is no need for `Child` to inherit from `Parent` and this would work the same:

```py
class Parent:
    @staticmethod
    def general_create(create_child_func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            print("Some general actions before")
            result = create_child_func(*args, **kwargs)
            print("Some general actions after")
            return result

        return wrapper


class Child:
    @Parent.general_create
    def create(self):
        print("Сreate actions for class Child")
        return "Result Child"


Child().create()
```

Infact there is also no need for a `Parent` class at all... You could just keep the `general_create` as a global function:

```py
def general_create(create_child_func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Some general actions before")
        result = create_child_func(*args, **kwargs)
        print("Some general actions after")
        return result

    return wrapper


class Child:
    @general_create
    def create(self):
        print("Сreate actions for class Child")
        return "Result Child"


Child().create()
```

Comment: I dont know how should i keep `general_create` as a global function, because general actions before/after keep in class `Parent`. Child classes use parent's methods, but complement their functionality in their own way. I have no idea how  to design my code another way.